# Just can't use Serial.parseInt();

Tags: arduino, parseint

I don't know what's wrong, I just can't use parseint function:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int data = Serial.parseInt();
  if (data == 1){
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  }
}
```

I did it with char, but I need to compare if a variable is higher than that number.

Comment: int data = Serial.parseInt();

Comment: Do you tried to add a `while(Serial.available() > 0){}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available() > 0){
      int data = Serial.parseInt();
      if (data == 1){
        digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
      }
  }
}
```

If the data input to the Serial monitor is a number, this should work.